# Promises and asynchronous code: how to throw a 500 status code inside a Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm stuck with these error since 3 days in a backend application:

```
[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

when i try to throw a 500 status error inside the code below.

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((results) => {
    let i = 0;
    for (const feature of results) {
      if (feature == true) albumFields.features.push(features[i]._id);
      else {
        res.status(500).send('Server Error'); //ERROR HERE
      }
      i++;
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
try {
  let album = new Album(albumFields);

  await album.save();

  res.json(album);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
  res.status(500).send('Server Error');
}
```

can someone suggest me the correct way of doing this?

it looks like it  run the code after the "Promise.all(..." before running the code inside

EDIT:
solved with the code below, thanks guys

```js
let featureIsFalse = false;
await Promise.all(promises)
  .then((results) => {
    let i = 0;
    for (const feature of results) {
      if (feature == false) {
        console.log('err');
      }
      if (feature == true) albumFields.features.push(features[i]._id);
      else {
        featureIsFalse = true;
      }
      i++;
    }
    console.log('result', results);
    console.log('albumFields', albumFields.features);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

if (featureIsFalse) res.status(500).send('Server Error');
else {
  try {
    // Create
    let album = new Album(albumFields);

    await album.save();

    res.json(album);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't `send` right away, defer that until the promise is resolved. Then check the status and respond accordingly.

Comment: you need to await the `Promise.all`.

Comment: `Cannot set headers after they are sent` means you can only respond once to a browser.  Meaning you can use only once `res.end()` or `res.json()` or `res.send()`. You're using `res.send()` inside a loop, that's a guaranteed crash.

Comment: solved thanks guys. the await solved the problems

Comment: Glad you got it working, but the code is still more complex than it needs to be. See my answer for a cleaner, shorter, and more understandable version.

Comment: `res.status(500).send('Server Error');` does not **`throw`** anything. If you did just that, it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The `try ... catch` is almost certainly running before all the promises resolve.

The flow is clearer if you use a Promise chain from top to bottom:

```js
Promise.all(promises)

  .then((results) => {
    let i = 0;
    for (const feature of results) {
      if (!feature) {
        throw { status: 500, message: 'Server Error' };
      }
      albumFields.features.push(features[i]._id);
      i++;
    }

    let album = new Album(albumFields);
    return album.save().then(() => album);
  })

  .then(album => {
    res.json(album);
  })

  .catch(err => {
    res.status(err.status || 500)
      .send(err.message || 'Server Error');
  });
```